# Is there an easy way to use oAuth2 without an AccountManager?

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, accountmanager

I'd like to use a web service in my app which uses oAuth2. The official Android docs suggest I use AccountManager for this, but it also states that third party apps aren't able to use the ACCOUNT_MANAGER permission. When adding the permission to my manifest:

```
android.permission.ACCOUNT_MANAGER
```

I get the following error: `Permission is only granted to system apps`

So how do I actually work with oAuth if I can't use AccountManager?

Answer (score 1):

These are the pre-Marshmallow permissions you would need to act as a client of `AccountManager`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
```

You can find out which calls need which permissions by looking at the [`AccountManager` documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).

`ACCOUNT_MANAGER` permission is for the service that responds to your app's requests.  That gives it ability to access authenticators directly.